A question about Möbius transformation and Beltrami forms
In the Page 170, Proposition 4.8.19 of John H. Hubbard's book "Teichmuller theory and applications to geometry, topology and dynamics", the author said:

Let $A: P^{1}\rightarrow P^{1}$ be a Möbius transformation, and $M(P^{1})^{A}$ be the space of $\mu\in M(P^{1})$ such that $A^{*}\mu=\mu$. Then the map $\mu\rightarrow f^{\mu}\circ A\circ (f^{\mu})^{-1}$ is an analytic mapping $M(P^{1})^{A}\rightarrow Aut P^{1}$

Let me explain the notation here, $P^{1}$ is the Riemann sphere, $M(P^{1})$ means the space of Beltrami forms of $P^{1}$. The pullback of Beltrami forms is defined as (See Proposition and Definition 4.8.10 in his book):

Let E, F be 1-dimensional vector spaces and let $u\in L_{\mathbb{R}}$(E,F) be an orientation-preserving isomorphism. Then there's a unique transformation $u^{*}:M(F)\rightarrow M(E)$ such that for any third 1-dimensional complex vector space G and any $v\in L_{\mathbb{R}}(F,G)$, we have
$u^{*}(\mu(v))=\mu(v\circ u)$. And the pullback transformation $u^{*}:M(F)\rightarrow M(E)$ is analytic

And in the proof of this proposition, he said:

Already the fact that $f^{\mu}\circ A\circ (f^{\mu})^{-1}$ is a Möbius transformation at all is a bit surprising, but it's easy to understand: the pull back by $f^{\mu}$ of the Beltrami form 0 (zero Beltrami form) is the Beltrami form $\mu$, which pulls back by A to $\mu$ again, since $\mu$ is A-invariant. Then $\mu$ pushes forward to 0, again by $f^{\mu}$.


But $f^{\mu}\circ A\circ (f^{\mu})^{-1}$ maps $0$, $1$ and $\infty$ to $f^{\mu}(A(0))$, $f^{\mu}(A(1))$, $f^{\mu}(A(\infty))$. These depend analytically on $\mu$, proving the proposition.

My question is, why he only need to verify the pullback of a specific Beltrami form 0 by a map is still 0,  to prove this map is a Möbius transformation?
==================================
My attempt to answer @Moishe Khan's question: In this book, formula 4.8.34 gives a expression of  pullback of Beltrami form:

For $f:U\rightarrow V$ a quasiconformal homomorphism, let z be coordinate of U and w be the coordinate of V. For any Beltrami form $\eta=[\eta]\frac{d\bar w}{dw}$, where $[\eta]$ is a function on V with values in unit disc D. We have


$f^{*}\eta=\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}+[\eta]\circ \overline{f(\frac{\partial f}{\partial  z})}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+[\eta]\circ \overline{f(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z})}}\frac{d\bar z}{dz}$

So for Beltrami form 0, $[$0$]=0$ and its pullback by $f^{\mu}$ is ($f^{\mu}$ is the normalized solution to Beltrami equation, which means that it fixes $ 0,1,\infty$ and satisfies $\frac{\partial f^{\mu}}{\partial \bar z}=\mu\frac{\partial f^{\mu}}{\partial z}$)
$(f^{\mu})^{*} $0$ =\frac{\frac{\partial f^{\mu}}{\partial \bar z}d\bar z}{\frac{\partial f^{\mu}}{\partial z}dz}=\mu$

This proof makes no sense to me (including "Bertram form"). Are you sure you copied correctly?

Perhaps, you should explain what Hubbard means by pullback in this setting: The usual pullback of a zero form (or tensor) by any map will be zero.

@MoisheKohan, Okay, I will explain more on pullback in my question, and I'm sure I copied the proof correctly after edition.

Then the answer is that a qc map satisfies distributional equation $\bar \partial f=0$ if and only if it is conformal.

@MoisheKohan, yes it's very near the truth, but if I don't remember wrongly, any bijective conformal map of $P^{1}$ is Möbius transformation right? So why $f^{\mu}$ is bijective?

By the very definition, qc maps are homeomorphisms.

@MoisheKohan You are right, I seem to ask a very vulgar question, thank you for your comments!
